# Redux is updating instantaneously, but react component has asynchronous lag

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

My component has a check box that will fire off a this.props.toggleChange action creator when clicked. In the toggleChange action creator, it will dispatch a TOGGLE_CONFIG_CHANGE, which is picked up by a Redux Saga. The inside of the saga function looks like this:

```
export function* toggledConfigSaga () {
    yield put(toggleConfigClicked()); // this fires off TOGGLE_CONFIG_CLICKED
    yield put(saveAllCurrentConfigsAndFetchServerStuff()); // this function will throw up a spinner as asynch actions complete
}
```

In my reducer, I have `CASE types.TOGGLE_CONFIG_CLICKED: return {...state, toggleConfig: !state.configChecked};`. In redux dev tools and console log the configClicked boolean is changed instantaneously on check box click(as one would expect). However, the check mark doesn't toggle until the asynch actions completes, giving it the illusion of a laggy button. What gives?

Comment: That's not expected. Can you post more code? Starting with the reducer that is hooked up to toggledConfigSaga, as well as your react component that consumes the toggleConfig